# Finding a formula for this sequence $-8, -14, 8, 14, -8, -14, 8, 14$

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

I couldn't find this on the whole internet. My life depends on solving this. Please help.
I must write a formula for this sequence
$-8,  -14,  8,  14,  -8,  -14,  8,  14$.

Comment: what about describing the positive or negativeness in terms of being representable by n=$4k-1$ or $4k$ (where $k$ is a natural number) and $n$ is the indice.

Comment: I must say that I am encountering such theatrics for the first time on Math SE.

Comment: What is the context in which your life depends on this?

Comment: $a_n=(8(1-n\bmod2)+14(n\bmod2))\cdot(-1)^{\lceil{n/2}\rceil}$

Comment: Is it not periodic with period 4? So you may merely write "period 4: repeat $-8,-14,8,14$" as is done on the OEIS.

Answer (score 4):

$f(x)=14 \cos (\pi x/2)-8 \sin(\pi x/2)$ does it, for $x=1,2,3,4,\cdots .$

Comment: You are so smart!

Comment: Eric: Once it became clear these were of period 4, and change sign when 2 is added, it was just picking the right constants.

Answer (score 0):

Consider for an indice $n$ that if n is divisible by 2 the absolute value of your sequence is 14, else the absolute value is 8.

Next if an indice $n$ can be represented by $4k-1$ or $4k$ for $k \in \Bbb N$ then the sequence value is positive, else the sequence value is negative.